# React Router not showing different components/pages after navbar selections

Tags: css, reactjs

I just made a navbar/sidebar using react, react-router, and CSS, and when I click on different options in the navbar, it reroutes the page, but does not show anything that is in each component/page. I think it might have to do with my CSS but I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the relevant code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Services from './pages/Services';
import AboutUs from './pages/AboutUs';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Sidebar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
          <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And here is my sidebar code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import * as FaIcons from 'react-icons/fa';
import * as AiIcons from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { SidebarData } from './SidebarData';
import './Sidebar.css';
import { IconContext } from 'react-icons';

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [sidebar, setSidebar] = useState(false);

  const showSidebar = () => setSidebar(!sidebar);

  return (
    <>
      <IconContext.Provider value={{ color: '#fff' }}>
        <div className="navbar">
          <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
            <FaIcons.FaBars onClick={showSidebar} />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <nav className={sidebar ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
          <ul className="nav-menu-items" onClick={showSidebar}>
            <li className="navbar-toggle">
              <Link to="#" className="menu-bars">
                <AiIcons.AiOutlineClose />
              </Link>
            </li>
            {SidebarData.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li key={index} className={item.cName}>
                  <Link to={item.path}>
                    {item.icon}
                    <span>{item.title}</span>
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </IconContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

And the CSS:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #060b26;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-bars {
  margin-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background: none;
}

.nav-menu {
  background-color: #060b26;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  transition: 850ms;
}

.nav-menu.active {
  left: 0;
  transition: 350ms;
}

.nav-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
  list-style: none;
  height: 60px;
}

.nav-text a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #f5f5f5;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 95%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 16px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.nav-text a:hover {
  background-color: #1a83ff;
}

.nav-menu-items {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  background-color: #060b26;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

Thanks so much for any help anyone can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
 <Route path="/aboutus" component={AboutUs} />
 <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
```

to

```js
<Route path="/" exact element={<Home/>} />
<Route path="/aboutus" element={<AboutUs/>} />
<Route path="/services" element={<Services/>} />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).